# How to send a html div to another by selecting form options

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I write a little javascript program where the user creates a Task (or another job he has to do) and choose the day where the job is to do and after entering the submit-button a card with this task should display in a specific div. Here my struggle. I don't understand how to send the card to a special container. I test this with some dummy code in a switch-statement and I think the switch-statement is the right way:

```js
const daySource = document.querySelector('#day')
const dayDestination = document.querySelector('.dayDestination')
const btnSubmit = document.querySelector('.pushData')


daySource.addEventListener('change', () => {

    switch(daySource.value) //value ist der Wochentag aus select/option
    {
        case 'montag':
            //dayDestination.value = daySource
            document.querySelector('#montag').classList.toggle('card', true)
            break
        case 'dienstag':
            //dayDestination.value = daySource
            document.querySelector('#dienstag').innerHTML="Test"
            break
        case 'mittwoch':
            //dayDestination.value = daySource
            document.querySelector('#mittwoch').innerHTML="Test"
            break
        case 'donnerstag':
            //dayDestination.value = daySource
            document.querySelector('#donnerstag').innerHTML="Test"
            break
        case 'freitag':
            //dayDestination.value = daySource
            document.querySelector('#freitag').innerHTML="Test"
            break
        }
    })
```

As you can see the section with the innerHTML works. But that's I think can not be the right way. Can I solve this with the classList.toggle()? At the moment this doesn't work. The html looks like this:
**Containers where the Card should shown**

```html
<div class="row">
              <header><h5><strong>Montag</strong></h5></header>
              <div class="col col-lg-12 col-12 col-md-12 mt-0 py-2 dropZone" id="montag">   
              </div>
              
              <header><h5><strong>Dienstag</strong></h5></header>
              <div class="col col-lg-12 col-12 col-md-12 mt-0 py-2 dropZone" id="dienstag">
              </div>
              
              <header><h5><strong>Mittwoch</strong></h5></header>
              <div class="col col-lg-12 col-12 col-md-12 mt-0 py-2 dropZone" id="mittwoch">
              </div>
              
              <header><h5><strong>Donnerstag</strong></h5></header>
              <div class="col col-lg-12 col-12 col-md-12 mt-0 py-2 dropZone" id="donnerstag"> 
              </div>
              
              <header><h5><strong>Freitag</strong></h5></header>
              <div class="col col-lg-12 col-12 col-md-12 mt-0 py-2 dropZone" id="freitag">
              </div>
              
              <header><h5><strong>Erledigt</strong></h5></header> 
              <div id="doneContainer" class="col col-lg-12 col-12 col-md-12 mt-0 py-2 dropZone">
              </div>
</div>
```

And thats the droplist:

```html
                    <select id="day" class="formData" name="day">
                      <option value="montag">Montag</option>
                      <option value="dienstag">Dienstag</option>
                      <option value="mittwoch">Mittwoch</option>
                      <option value="donnerstag">Donnerstag</option>
                      <option value="freitag">Freitag</option>
                    </select>
```

I'am new to JS and there is much I have to learn. I hope someone of you can help me.

Comment: The `toggle` when you chose "Montag" works, what's the problem here? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to store a card which is structured with some div's for a TicketID, a Task and a date. Its not a single html-Element. In my example above, "card" is the classname of the outer div.

Comment: @iamdlm Yes it seems to work something in the "background". The container for the monday ist pushed a little bit to the right side, but the card is not shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve and `toggle` does not work as you think it does.
Either way, if you want to display the day selected on card you can do it like this:
Html:

```
<div id="ticket" style="card">
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
daySource.addEventListener('change', () => {
    document.getElementById("ticket").innerHTML = "You selected: " + daySource.value;
});
```

Or you can have a card per day and just toggle a "visible" class on the selected card, like so:
Html:

```
<div id="card_montag" style="card">
</div>
<div id="dienstag" style="card">
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
daySource.addEventListener('change', () => {
    var element = document.getElementById("card_" + daySource.value);
    element.classList.toggle("visible");
})
```

CSS:

```
.card {
  display: none;
}

.card.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

Hope any of this options get you to where you want.

Comment: I create the cards dynamically with EJS as Template Engine. If the user send the data (task and ticketID) from the form to the server, a new card should render on the page. So there is no static card displayed. When the data is send it should rendered in one of the Containers (Monday - Friday) and which container this is depends from the day the user choose in the form.

Answer (score 0):

Until now I found no solution how to get a new generated task into a specific div. Maybay toggle is the wrong method, but which is the right one then? I think I have to set the Destination-Container equal to the Source-Card, but how to do that in practice?
Thats the card I will send to the div:

```
<!-- Post-it/Card-->
       <section class="card draggable" id="card_montag">s
          </div>


          <div class="card-header cardColor">Ticket-ID: <%= tasks[i].ticketID %>
          </div>

          <div class="card-body">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Aufgabe: <%= tasks[i].task %> 
            </label>
            <hr>
            <label for="checkedSource" class="checkbox-inline"><input id="checked" name="checkedSource" type="checkbox"> &nbsp;Erledigt
            </label>
          </div>

          <div class="card-footer cardColor">von: <strong><%= user.username %></strong> - <i><%= date.join(" ") + " " + time.join(":")   %> </i>
          </div>
          <button class="btn warningBtn" id="deleteTask" data-taskid="<%= tasks[i].id %>"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
          </button>

        </section>
```